# How to run a cron job that run every day at 6:15 am, i do know how to run every 15 minutes

Tags: cron

i have this: */5 6-22 * * * *

This will run every 5 minutes from 6 to 23.

I want to know if it is posible that the run begins at 6:15 to 22:40.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't over-engineer it.

```
15-55/5 6    * * *  /usr/bin/foo
*/5     7-21 * * *  /usr/bin/foo
0-40/5  22   * * *  /usr/bin/foo
```

Answer (score -3):

```
let timecheck=$(date +%H%M) && if [ $timecheck -ge 615 ]; then if [ $timecheck -le 2240 ]; then { run_your_job.sh;}; else { echo 'do nothing';}; fi; fi;
```

Comment: You didn't know that test has an "and" too?